# Flutter : Achieved Sliverappbar Shape

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm found some Appbar design in Dribble https://dribbble.com/shots/9175650-Beauty-Salon-App/attachments/1218583?mode=media , I try to create same like that but i confused get border radius each other side.

Trial 1  Without Background :

[image]

Trial 2 With Scaffold Background Color Blue

[image]

Trial 3 With background Color Deep Orange

[image]

How can i achieved appbar design like the link ?

## Source Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_iconpicker/flutter_iconpicker.dart';

class TestingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = "/testing-screen";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: mediaQuery.size.height / 4,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(80))),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  height: mediaQuery.size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(80))),
                  child: Center(child: Text('data')),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use [`CustomClipper`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) to do this, with a method of `Path` `quadraticBezierTo`:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.orange),
            ClipPath(
              clipper: TheCustomClipper(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TheCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height / 3);
    var firstControlPoint = Offset(0, size.height / 3.5); // adjust the height to move start of the first curve
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 4.2, size.height / 3.5 + 10); // adjust the width to add the end controll point and height to move end of the first curve

    var secControlPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height / 2.8); // adjust the height to move end of the second curve
    var secEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height / 3 - 40); // adjust the width to add the right first controll point and height to move start of the second curve

    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        secControlPoint.dx, secControlPoint.dy, secEndPoint.dx, secEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 3);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Do note that, I only added curve to first widget. If you want to add another `CustomClipper` to the first `Container` of the `Stack`, do it by doing the reverse of the logic.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Source Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../shared/app_colors.dart';

class WelcomenPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = 'welcomen_page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipPath(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: AppColors.primary,
            ),
            clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomWaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * .65);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(0, size.height * .75);
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 6, size.height * .75);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width / 1.2, size.height * .75);

    var secControlPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height * .75);
    var secEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height * 0.85);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        secControlPoint.dx, secControlPoint.dy, secEndPoint.dx, secEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

**Output:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yssy2.png)